# Unable to lower screen brightness 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I had this issue since i installed ubuntu 13.04 long ago, and i have tried missing around with the gedit files but no joy.

Graphics card: intel integrated graphics 3000HD

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Modify the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

If it doesn't work try changing the same line to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` and run `sudo update-grub` again.

This works for some backlight problems.

Comment: Tried it but no luck